# Initial Value Problems defined on some interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a$ be a positive real number. Find all of solutions, defined on (−a, a), for the following initial-value problem:

$|y'(x)| + y(x) = 0$, and $y(0) = -1$.

My progress: I struggle to understand the correlation between given $a$ and solution of the DE. Meanwhile, is it allowed in such problems to divide into 2 cases and solve them separately? Any help would be strongly welcomed!

Comment: I reverted your last edit; concealing a question, especially after it has been answered, is not considered as good behavior here. Just leave it as it is, it's a good question. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a solution $y \in C^1((-a,a);\mathbb{R})$, consider breaking it into cases when $y' = \pm y$. You can do this because any solution $y$ which is differential at $t =0$ and satisfies $y(0) = -1$, will have that $y'(t)$ will not change sign in a neighborhood of $t=0$ since $|y'(0)| = 1 \implies y'(0) = \pm 1$.

Case 1: 
$$y' = -y, \ y(0) = -1 \quad (1)$$
then $y(t) = -e^{-t}$ is the unique $C^1$ solution of $(1)$.

Case 2:
$$y' = y, \ y(0) = -1 \quad (2)$$
then $y(t) = - e^{t}$ is the unique $C^1$ solution of $(2)$. Note that in both cases 
$$|y'| + y = 0, \ y(0) = -1 $$
And therefore you have two $C^1$ solutions to your IVP, $y_{\pm}(t) = - e^{\pm t}$ globally defined in time (i.e you can take $a=\infty$).

Comment: The same argument will not hold, but I believe the only solution will be $y\equiv 0$, however I am not sure how to show that.

Comment: @matematleta you are assuming $y'=-y$ or $y'= y$ on some neighborhood $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ of $x=0$ and applyinng a theorem about LINEAR equations. But that does not work completely because C^1 functions like $x^2\sin(1/x)$ do not have a definite sign in any neighborhood of $x=0$ and this is not a linear problem. I think it can be shown, but it may need a bit more care.

Comment: @Dayton yes, you are right. I need to think about this.

Comment: @Dayton one possibility to show that $y=0$ is the unique solution would be to assume wlog $[-a,a]$ is closed, and show that if $p'\in \mathscr P$ is any nonzero polynomial, then $|p'(x)|+p(x)$ s.t. $p(0)=0$ is bounded away from $0$, uniformly on $\mathscr P$, then apply Stone-Weierstrass

Comment: @Matematleta That could likely work. I posted here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3662529/ivp-with-indefinite-interval/3663755#3663755 a solution which allows us to apply linear uniqueness and existence theory.