# How to solve the differential equations that contain absolute term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the ODE in the form of $$|y'(x)| + y(x) = 0$$ given that the solution is continuous on interval (-k,k). If there is provided initial condition $$y(x_0)=y_0$$ I am not sure how to solve it so what I did is taking $$|y'(x)| = -y'(x) $$ when $$y_0 < 0$$ and  $$|y'(x)| = y'(x) $$ when $$y_0 > 0$$ and then solve the separable equation normally. Is my method correct?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note a very similar question was recently asked, but with the specific initial condition of $y_0 = -1$ only, at [Initial Value Problems defined on some interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3662450/602049).